# How do I turn off the Magic Keyboard (A1644)?

Tags: bluetooth, keyboard

I have the Apple Magic Keyboard model A1644, which was [released in 2015](https://arstechnica.com/gadgets/2015/10/mini-review-apples-new-magic-keyboard-magic-mouse-2-and-magic-trackpad-2/):

> [image]

Both this and the Magic Trackpad 2 have switches that allow you to turn it on (green) or off (white). I find that the switch on the trackpad works just fine. However, oftentimes when I try to turn off my keyboard and put it in my bag, I'll find out that the keyboard was on the entire time and draining my computer's battery due to random keystrokes being tapped. It's as though the hardware switch is broken or not respected by the keyboard.

Is there any way to shut off this keyboard and ensure it's shut off?

Answer (score 11):

I've tried several instances of the A1644 keyboard, and the hardware switch seems to be inherently spotty. Unlike with the trackpad--where you can be confident that when you see it in the off (white) position, it's actually off--you have no such assurances with the keyboard. You *must* verify that it was actually shut off.

The process typically involves:

1. Turn the switch to the off position.

   You'll see a notification saying the keyboard was disconnected, however, you can't always trust this.
2. Start typing on the keyboard.

   If the keyboard wasn't fully shut off, this is when you'll see a notification saying the keyboard was connected again, meaning it wasn't fully shut off.
3. Repeat the process until it's actually turned off.

Tips:

- Sometimes moving the switch all the way to the left (off position) is *never* going to shut off your keyboard. Instead, you need to move it all the way to the left (100% off), and then move it a tiny bit back to the right, so that it's in the 90% off position. Again you should test it before throwing it back in your bag due to the flakiness of the switch.

Comment: That sounds like the switch is dirty or has been knocked at some time in its life - it's a hard life in a bag rather than on a desk. Take it well away from the computer, so it cannot possibly connect, then flick the switch rapidly [firmly but gently] left/right a dozen or more times. If it was dirty that should go some way to cleaning it. If it's been banged, there's little you can do about it. Apple keyboards are not really repairable. I've never had one where the switch has failed, but I've never put one in a bag.

Comment: Can confirm this is the switch issue. Keyboard can be switched off if you put switch in off state gently, (without pushing it all the way)

Comment: Same thing here, and I was trying to force it to the left to no avail... Awesome tip that 90%, I just applied a small force to the right and I got the Turned off message, thanks!!

Comment: shouldn't be, but 90% or just do not push it all the way works! I wonder if apple knows about it

Comment: It's the same for me as for @DenisBazhenov - moving thumb back from 100% OFF to ~90% doesn't work, instead I have to push it gently from ON to OFF state until at some point it disconnects. All you need is practice (or another better kbd:)

Comment: OMG, I cannot believe that the 90% off position tip worked! That's insane.